# Update text of UITabBarController items on a button click

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I want to update the text of `UITabBarController` items on a button click like this:

[image]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
for(UITabBarItem *tabBarItem in [self.tabBarController.tabBar items])
{
    NSLog(@"%@", tabBarItem.title);
    //here u can change title
    //tabBarItem.title = @"some title";
}
```

or get acces to current tab's title

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.tabBarController.tabBar.title);
```

Answer (score 0):

`UIViewController` has a property `tabBarController` which is a pointer to the tab bar (`UITabBarController`). Then go nuts with the tab bar. If you just want the tab bar item of the current viewController then `UIViewController` has the property `tabBarItem`.